I always get redirected to home page when refresh any page in the whole application
main.jsx
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <ToastContainer />
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
)

app.jsx
const App = () => (
  <CustomerRouters />
);

customerRouters.jsx
const CustomerRouters = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <Navbar />
            </div>
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/cart' element={<Cart />} />
                <Route path='/:levelOne/:levelTwo/:levelThree' element={<ProductPage />} />
                <Route path='/product/:productId' element={<ProductDetails />} />
                <Route path='/checkout' element={<Checkout />} />
                <Route path='/account/order' element={<Order />} />
                <Route path='/account/order/:orderId' element={<OrderDetails />} />
                <Route path='/payment/:orderId' element={<PaymentSuccess />} />
                <Route path='/login' element={<HomePage />} />
                <Route path='/register' element={<HomePage />} />
                <Route path='/' element={<HomePage />} />
            </Routes>
            <div>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

auth redux state
actionType
export const REGISTER_REQUEST = 'REGISTER_REQUEST';
export const REGISTER_SUCCESS = 'REGISTER_SUCCESS';
export const REGISTER_FAILURE = 'REGISTER_FAILURE';

export const LOGIN_REQUEST = 'LOGIN_REQUEST';
export const LOGIN_SUCCESS = 'LOGIN_SUCCESS';
export const LOGIN_FAILURE = 'LOGIN_FAILURE';

export const GET_USER_REQUEST= 'GET_USER_REQUEST';
export const GET_USER_SUCCESS= 'GET_USER_SUCCESS';
export const GET_USER_FAILURE = 'GET_USER_FAILURE';

export const LOGOUT = 'LOGOUT';

action
import axios from "axios";
import { API_BASE_URL } from "../../config/apiConfig";
import { GET_USER_FAILURE, GET_USER_REQUEST, GET_USER_SUCCESS, LOGIN_FAILURE, LOGIN_REQUEST, LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGOUT, REGISTER_FAILURE, REGISTER_REQUEST, REGISTER_SUCCESS } from "./ActionType";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

const registerRequest = () => ({ type: REGISTER_REQUEST });
const registerSuccess = (user) => ({ type: REGISTER_SUCCESS, payload: user });
const registerFailure = (error) => ({ type: REGISTER_FAILURE, payload: error });

export const register = (userData) => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(registerRequest());
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(`${API_BASE_URL}/auth/signup`, userData);
        const user = response.data;
        if (user.token) {
            localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
        }
        // dispatch({ type: 'REGISTER_SUCCESS', payload: user });
        dispatch(registerSuccess(user.token));
        toast.success(user.message, {
            autoClose: 2000,
            pauseOnHover: false,
        });

    } catch (error) {
        
        dispatch(registerFailure(error.response.data.error));
        toast.error(error.response.data.error, {
            autoClose: 2000,
            pauseOnHover: false,
        });
    }
}


const loginRequest = () => ({ type: LOGIN_REQUEST });
const loginSuccess = (user) => ({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: user });
const loginFailure = (error) => ({ type: LOGIN_FAILURE, payload: error });

export const login = (userData) => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(loginRequest());
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(`${API_BASE_URL}/auth/signin`, userData);
        const user = response.data;
        if (user.token) {
            localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
        }
        toast.success(user.message, {
            autoClose: 2000,
            pauseOnHover: false,
        });
        dispatch(loginSuccess(user.token));

    } catch (error) {
        toast.error(error.response.data.error, {
            autoClose: 2000,
            pauseOnHover: false,
        });
        dispatch(loginFailure(error.message));
    }
}


const getUserRequest = () => ({ type: GET_USER_REQUEST });
const getUserSuccess = (user) => ({ type: GET_USER_SUCCESS, payload: user });
const getUserFailure = (error) => ({ type: GET_USER_FAILURE, payload: error });

export const getUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(getUserRequest());
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${API_BASE_URL}/users/profile`, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
            }
        });
        const user = response.data;
        dispatch(getUserSuccess(user));

    } catch (error) {
        dispatch(getUserFailure(error.message));
    }
}


export const logout = () => async (dispatch) => {
    localStorage.clear();
    toast.success("Logged out successfully", {
        autoClose: 2000,
        pauseOnHover: false,
    });
    dispatch({ type: LOGOUT, payload: null });
}

reducer
const initialState = {
    user: null,
    error: null,
    loading: false,
    jwt: null
}


export const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LOGIN_REQUEST':
        case 'REGISTER_REQUEST':
        case 'GET_USER_REQUEST':
            return {
                ...state,
                error: null,
                loading: true,
            }
        case 'LOGIN_SUCCESS':
        case 'REGISTER_SUCCESS':
            return {
                ...state,
                error: null,
                loading: false,
                jwt: action.payload
            }
        case 'GET_USER_SUCCESS':
            return {
                ...state,
                error: null,
                loading: false,
                user: action.payload
            }
        case 'LOGIN_FAILURE':
            return {
                ...state,
                error: action.payload.error,
                loading: false,
            }
        case 'LOGOUT':
            return initialState
        default:
            return state
    }
}

I don't know what is the issue I am facing.
I tried for straight 3-4 days but couldn't find the solution to this redirecting issue
I tried all the related issues in redux and that they all are working perfectly as expected but why is this issue occurring
I removed all the errors and warnings in the console.
Then every possible error removed them
edit*
after clicking checkout button it will redirects me to the razorpay portal then after successful payment it redirects me to the payment success page but there is automatically reloads and redirects me to the home page but for a glimpse I can saw the payment success page there was rendered the code which is written but the I was log out from there because I can saw the signIn button in the navbar. But I am getting the jwt from local storage which means it is logging out but it is losing the state that's why it is giving me null values for the auth state


import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const PaymentSuccess = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const auth = useSelector(state => state.auth);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Auth State:', auth);
        console.log('Token:', localStorage.getItem("token"));

        // Redirect to login if JWT is not available
        if (!auth.jwt) {
            navigate('/login');
        }
    }, [location, auth, navigate]);

    return (
        <div>
            <p>Payment Success Page</p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default PaymentSuccess;




How are you handling your private route? I can see you're saving your token to the local storage but are you retrieving it anywhere in your application to persist your application state and handle protected routes?

When you refresh local state is lost (and redux, unless you have a package to persist it). You need to address this when doing private routes that need some kind of login

actually i am not having protected route usage in my react app it is handling by backend only

I think the state is not lost while refreshing I see by consoling in every step

Can you show how you're using the token stored in local storage to handle public and protected route? How are you determining that a page should only be accessed if there is a token and others should be access even without a token? This is important to be able to provide a solution suitable for what you really want to achieve.

There is nothing in the code you have shared that redirects to your home page. Please [edit] to clarify the problem and include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with.

edited the post please look

Redux stores are not persisted by default, so reloading the page wipes the state. Is this issue only happening on the "/payment/:orderId" route that renders PaymentSuccess? Are you looking to implement a more generalized route protection implementation? Is there any code that checks/sets the state.auth state when the app mounts?

If you are using an older version of react-router-dom try adding the exact to the homepage path.
<Route exact path='/' element={<HomePage />} />


OP is not using older version and RRDv6 routes are always exactly matched, there is no exact prop.

You haven't provided enough information to be able to help provide a proper implementation that could help solve the issue you're experiencing but I'm hoping this probable solution of mine is enough to help you overcome your issues.
First of all, I noticed you're saving your token to local storage, but you're not retrieving it in your application to be able to handle secure and protected routes. Therefore, when you refresh your page, the jwt state gets lost and you get redirected to the home page which is an accessible route. I'm going to implement a PrivateRoute component that can be wrapped around all the pages you're expecting users to not be able to access unless they have been properly authenticated.
//PrivateRoute.jsx

import React from "react";
import { Navigate, useLocation, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const PrivateRoute = ({ ...rest }) => {
  const token = useSelector((state) => state.auth.jwt); //This is pointing to the jwt state property of your reducer

  const location = useLocation();

  if (token) {
    return <Outlet {...rest} />;
  }

  return <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} />;
};

export default PrivateRoute;


You can import the PrivateRoute to the CustomRoute you have defined. I have also refactored the CustomRoute for better structure.
export default function CustomRoutes() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Navbar />
      </div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/">
          <Route index element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path="login" element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path="register" element={<HomePage />} />
        </Route>
        <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
          <Route path="/">
            <Route path="products">
              <Route index element={<div>Product Page</div>} />
              <Route
                path=":productId"
                element={<div>Product Details Page</div>}
              />
            </Route>
            <Route path="cart" element={<Cart />} />
            <Route path="checkout" element={<Checkout />} />
            <Route path="account">
              <Route index element={<p>Account Page</p>} />
              <Route path="order">
                <Route index element={<p>Order Page</p>} />
                <Route path=":orderId" element={<p>Order Page</p>} />
              </Route>
            </Route>
            <Route path="payment">
              <Route index element={<p>Payment Page</p>} />
              <Route path=":orderId" element={<p>Payment Success</p>} />
            </Route>
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
      <div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

This implies that all the pages wrap around the PrivateRoute component would not be accessible unless jwt state is true. While other pages outside the PrivateRoute would become a public route and can be accessed even if the user isn't authenticated.
Also, you might need to initialize your jwt reducer state with the value of the token saved in the local storage. This way, if there is already an existing token in the local storage, your current page would persist even if it's a protected route.
const initialState = {
    user: null,
    error: null,
    loading: false,
    jwt: localStorage.getItem("token") || null
}

I hope this helps in solving your current issues.
